# perforce sync no such files

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate

I am trying to setup perforce. I installed p4v and setup workspace.
Then I ran

```
C:\"Program Files"\Perforce\p4 -p perforce-test:1500 -u test-user -c test-user_test sync //test-folder/test/
```

But I get error `//test-folder/test/ no such files(s)`

I can see files and folder exist in p4v depo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the path:

```
//test-folder/test/...
```

Directories aren't objects in Perforce, they're just part of the file name -- so you don't sync a directory called "//test-folder/test/", you sync all the files whose paths match the pattern "//test-folder/test/...".

Answer (score 1):

Use the “...” in the end

e.g.

Wrong ：  `p4 sync //test-folder/test/`

Right :   `p4 sync //test-folder/test/...`