# Perforce sync - No such files

Tags: perforce

I am trying to get a folder from a depot with "Get Revision" and "Forced" option via perforce in commandline. To do that, I got the below command from the UI.

```
p4 sync -f //MyFolder/Project/Cool Stuff...#head
```

The command gives me an error -

```
//MyFolder/Project/Cool - no such file(s).
Stuff/...#head - no such file(s).
```

I also tried `p4 sync -f //MyFolder/Project/Cool Stuff...` and got a similar error. I did not find an answer here either - [perforce sync no such files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003863/perforce-sync-no-such-files). How do I make this work ?

**PS** - I only need to sync one folder via commandline because its huge and I want to automate the sync process instead of having to do it manually everyday via the UI. I don't really do much on the perforce UI either. Therefore, I don't need to learn any more perforce commandline than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote command line arguments that have spaces in them; otherwise they're interpreted as two different arguments (which is why you get two different errors, each referring to a different part of the path).

```
p4 sync -f "//MyFolder/Project/Cool Stuff...#head"
```